# Error on opening an MDI ChildForm from another MDI ChildForm's TButton via TMenuItem on MDI ParentForm

Tags: delphi, mdichild, mdiparent

I have 2 MDIChild Forms and an MDIParent Form with a TMainMenu. In the TMainMenu, I have the following TMenuItem.OnClick procedure to open ChildForm2:

```
procedure TfrmMain.miOpenChildForm2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TfrmChildForm2.Create(self).Show;
end;
```

Now, I want to access the above procedure from ChildForm1 by a TButton.OnClick procedure below:

```
procedure TfrmChildForm1.btnOpenChildForm2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmMain.miOpenChildForm2Click; // Error Here: E2035 Not enough actual parameters
End;
```

I am getting an error on the above second procedure:

> E2035 Not enough actual parameters

I don't know exactly where to correct it. I tried putting '()' at the end of the procedure call, but no avail.

Comment: You didn't pass enough parameters. You passed zero. It seems that you need to pass more than zero. Consulting the definition of the method would tell you what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure definition

```
procedure TfrmMain.miOpenChildForm2Click(Sender: TObject);
```

tells you that the procedure expects to receive a parameter `Sender` of type `TObject`. Calling it with `frmMain.miOpenChildForm2Click;` does not pass that parameter. The parameter is not optional.

`Sender` is intended to tell you what triggered the event, for use in cases where it matters, such as when you're using one event handler for multiple controls. It allows you to differentiate where the call to the event originated.

You can use the button or menu item that was clicked in the call as the parameter

```
frmMain.miOpenChildForm2Click(btnOpenChildForm2);
```

If it doesn't matter where the call came from, you can pass `nil` instead

```
frmMain.miOpenChildForm2Click(nil);
```

As a note: MDI has been deprecated for at least a decade, and Windows has not had much support for it for at least that long. Modern applications do not use MDI, and new development most likely shouldn't include it either.

Comment: Alternatively, you can call the public [`Click()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.Click) method of the `TMenuItem`, which will call its `OnClick` event handler with the `TMenuItem` as the `Sender`, eg: `frmMain.miOpenChildForm2.Click;`

Comment: Another alternative is to create a `TActionList` with a `TAction` whose `OnExecute` event creates the ChildForm2, and then assign that `TAction` to both the `TMenuItem` and the `TButton` so they trigger the same action when they are clicked.

Comment: So sad to hear the MDI is deprecated already. Do you suggest that I have to remove MDI from my application development? Right now its a main part of my program though challenging sometimes like this case. Or can you suggest other way around instead of MDI?

Comment: @Juke: What do you mean *already*? It hasn't had any improvements or changes since the early days of Windows, isn't being supported by bug fixes, and no one has been using it for at least a decade even by MS. Users don't expect that antiquated interface any longer, either. It's still around only because MS doesn't like removing support for things to support old legacy applications.

Comment: I see @KenWhite. Thank you for shedding light on this. In the meantime, I'll be okay but when I get the chance I might change the interfacing of my forms later. I came across some applications that were using MDI till now and they are still doing great. Perhaps, the basic functionalities of MDI are still working and could no longer expect more from it.